# Updating existing entity in endpoints-proto-datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am using Endpoints-proto-datastore written by Danny Hermes for Google App Engine and need help figuring out how to update an entity.. My model for what I need to update is the following

```
class Topic(EndpointsModel):
    #_message_fields_schema = ('id','topic_name','topic_author')
    topic_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    topic_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    topic_author = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)
    topic_num_views = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    topic_num_replies = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    topic_flagged = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    topic_followers = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
    topic_avg_rating = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.0)
    topic_total_rating = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.0)
    topic_num_ratings = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    topic_raters = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

And as you can see, the rating properties have a default of 0. So each time a topic is rated, I need to update each of the rating properties. However, none of my properties is the actual rating being provided by the user. How can i pass in the value the user rated the topic to be able to update the properties in the model? Thanks!

Comment: Danny here. You essentially want two things -- the rater and the rating -- to be sent? From `topic_raters` I surmise the rater would be a `KeyProperty` and the rating would be a float or int?

Comment: @bossylobster Yes, thats correct. I need to pass in the key of the user's profile entity that I use for extending user object which is the model called UserProfile. And I need to pass in the rating the user selected. I am also using the Endpoints JavaScript client library that I set up if that changes anything. So given that a user gives a rating of 3 out of 5, I need to add 3 to total_rating, 1 to num_ratings, and update avg_rating based on those two. Then add the user's profile key to raters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by having an "alias" property called `rating` associated with your `UserModel`:

```
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsAliasProperty

class UserModel(EndpointsModel):

    ...

    def rating_set(self, value):
        # Do some validation
        self._rating = value

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=rating_set)
    def rating(self):
        return self._rating
```

This will allow ratings to be sent with `UserModel`s in requests but won't require those ratings to be stored.

You're better off using the OAuth 2.0 token for the user and calling `endpoints.get_current_user()` to determine who the user is in the request.

Something like a dedicated model for ratings could be much easier:

```
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsUserProperty

class Rating(EndpointsModel):
    rater = EndpointsUserProperty(raise_unauthorized=True)
    rating = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    topic = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Topic)
```

and then transactionally retrieving the `Topic` from the datastore and updating it in a request method decorated by `@Rating.method`.